# Temporary s3 buckets or different storage methodologies to support AWS batch execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, storage, aws-batch, data-exchange

I want to pass data to and from an AWS batch instance.
The current workflow requires an s3 bucket as support, it requires to take care of s3 data upload and disposal and to create an existing bucket just for this data exchange.

Is it possible to create a temporary s3 bucket or common workspace with automatic object/bucket disposal? Are there other techniques that can be used for simple data exchange between local code and an AWS Batch instance?

Comment: Take a look at the [object lifecycle management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html).

Comment: This might solve one part of the problem, but it requires to create and specify a bucket beforehand. Is there a way to automate this procedure, e.g. a different AWS storage where you just upload some data with specific lifecycle metadata, and use it for data exchange? (and it gets deleted automatically after n days?)

Comment: This is exactly what object lifecycle management does. You can configure things to be automatically deleted after certain number of days. You don't need a different storage type on S3 for this.

Comment: I agree, but it requires creating and specifying an s3 bucket beforehand, which I would like to bypass. Sorry if it was unclear in the question.

Comment: Why would you like to bypass it? What's the problem with creating such a temporary bucket beforehand? Doesn't cost anything if objects are cleared away anyway.

Comment: I know it's not an excessive cost. I just wanted to understand if there was an alternative AWS paradigm or a temporary storage solution without the need to reinvent the wheel. Thanks

Comment: S3 is the answer.